# Trying Prebinding converse.js with php to an openfire server

Tags: php, xmpp, converse.js, prebinding

So I have a web site where you can login with a username and a password and I would like that with that one login, a session could be generated for converse.js

I've been reading the documentation and the SSO Support and I ended in an example repo for prebinding with php. [link](https://github.com/priyadi/roundcube-converse.js-xmpp-plugin/tree/master/php/xmpp-prebind-php)

I prepared an object wich should be the model I'll call from my controller, but there are some parameters I'm not sure what they are.

```
$xmppPrebind = new XmppPrebind('your-jabber-host.tld', 'http://your-jabber-host/http-bind/', 'Your XMPP Clients resource name', false, false);
$xmppPrebind->connect($username, $password);
$xmppPrebind->auth();
$sessionInfo = $xmppPrebind->getSessionInfo(); // array containing sid, rid and jid
```

The 3rd parameter on the XmppPrebind Constructor 'Your XMPP clients resource name' what is that?

Also when doing the connect function the parameters $username and $password...are those the one I get from my loging form (the one on my website) or some valid user & password pair on the openfire server?

Answer (score 1):

- 'Your XMPP Clients resource name' = Any name you want, example: myWebChat
- "Also when doing the connect function the parameters $username and $password...are those the one I get from my loging form (the one on my website) or some valid user & password pair on the openfire server?" Use prebind to make user autologin to your xmpp server when they login to your website, so the account must valid on xmpp server.

Answer (score 0):

$sessionInfo will have sid rid and jid. Third parameter will be added to jid. You will get something like:

"you@conference.conversejs.orgYour XMPP Clients resource name"

So just set it empty.

I guess only first or third parameters should be set, not both in one time.